# How can I read data from an Excel sheet using ExcelJS library?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, webdriver-io, exceljs

It keeps on giving file not found exception. Below is the function which i am calling to read data from the excel sheet:

```js
import excel from 'exceljs'

getDataFromExcel(sheetName,rowNum,colNum){

    //const excel = require('exceljs')
    let wb  = new excel.Workbook()
    wb.xlsx.readFile('../testData/Full-TestData.xlsx').then(()=>{

        let sheet = wb.getWorksheet(sheetName)
        let data = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(cellNum).value().toString()
        return data

    })
}
```

I am trying to read data from an excel sheet to use it in my script instead of hard coding however i am getting no file found exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyX2x.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo will work

Save as `read.js` name under `src` directory.

```js
function columnName (index) {
    var cname = String.fromCharCode(65 + ((index - 1) % 26))
    if (index > 26)
        cname = String.fromCharCode(64 + (index - 1) / 26) + cname
    return cname
}

function getDataFromExcel (sheet, rowNum, colNum) {
    cell = columnName(colNum) + String(rowNum)
    text = sheet.getCell(cell).text
    return text
}

module.exports = { getDataFromExcel, columnName }
```

Save as `client.js` name under `src` directory.

```js
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs')
const excel = require("./read");

const fileName = '../testData/Full-TestData.xlsx';
const wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook()
const sheetName = 'contact angle'


wb.xlsx.readFile(fileName).then(() => {
    sheet = wb.getWorksheet(sheetName)

    // A1
    rowNum = 1
    colNum = 1
    cell = excel.columnName(colNum) + String(rowNum)
    text =  excel.getDataFromExcel(sheet, rowNum, colNum)
    console.log(cell + ": " + text)

    // B3
    rowNum = 3
    colNum = 2
    cell = excel.columnName(colNum) + String(rowNum)
    text =  excel.getDataFromExcel(sheet, rowNum, colNum)
    console.log(cell + ": " + text)

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
})
```

##### Result

```
$ node client.js
A1: SDM
B3: 75.8
```

##### Install dependency

At `src` directory.

```
npm install exceljs
```

Using this excel file
Save as `Full-TestData.xlsx` name under `testData` directory.

```
https://figshare.com/articles/dataset/Test_data_xlsx/22040333
```

[image]

##### File structure

```
├── src
│   └── read.js
│   └── client.js
└── testData
    └── Full-TestData.xlsx
```

##### Run it

at `src` directory.

```
node client.js
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you!. I want to have a single method written with parameters as sheetname, row number, column number. Whenever i call this method in another js file, it should give me the cell values present in the xlsx sheet. Can you help me here?

Comment: Where did you get this method?  text = sheet.getCell(cell).text.

Comment: @Sndeep, I updated other.js(client.js) call the getDataFromExcel() function. Can you review it?

Comment: the 'text = sheet.getCell(cell).text' is exceljs function in [here](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#string-value)

Comment: Can you add an option to run this code snippet? I want to check if your code is able to retrieve the data from the given sheet or not?

Comment: I tried however i am getting this error: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".xlsx"

Comment: Did you install the `exceljs` dependency by  `npm install excelhs` at src directory? It will generate package.json file and `node_modules` sub directory at `src` directory.

Comment: I have added a link to the original question. This shows the actual project structure. I installed exceljs at the project level.

Comment: Your configuration and my configuration is different. Can you try it change from '../testData/Full-TestData.xlsx' to './testData/Full-TestData.xlsx' ?
The file location prefix `../` means upper directory, `./` means sub directory.

Comment: Thanks for informing. I know this and made those necessary changes based on the location of the xlsx file as per my project directory.

Comment: If not related to a file location. I think something wrong install `exceljs`. Can you try `npm cache clean --force` then reinstall exceljs `npm install exceljs`

Comment: I tested my code on windows and ubuntu. It works on both OS.

Comment: What is content of my demo program's `package.json` file? It created by `npm install exceljs`